# Use 2 modes of references in the same document

Tags: biblatex

how complex is it in biblatex to combine two referencing styles? I understand that this is not usual, but in a new editorial design that I am working on, the references are used with the author/year model and the sources with the footnote model of page.

Basically what I want is to be able to use \cite (obtaining an author/year output on the page) and footcite (obtaining a footnote output on the page) in the same document

Thanks for any help

**adding details to the question**

The ultimate goal of doing the work through biblatex is to be able to use the op. cit., and ibidem automatically in the footnotes, since in the books of this collection the sources are many, really many to try to keep track of the op. cit., and ibidem manually. In the author/year style, is not placed op. cit. or ibidem. The final list only contains the references

The editorial style of the collection is based on the following principles to separate references from sources

What do we understand by bibliography?: the sum of the sources plus the references;

What do we understand by source?: we refer to the set of data that uniquely identifies a resource that has been used to prepare another document and that meets the following premises:

1. written in the first person singular;
2. it is written in the same period as the one studied;
3. does not have mentions of other references.

What do we understand by reference?: we refer to the set of data that uniquely identifies a resource that has been used for the preparation of another document and that has its mark or indication within the text.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a few more details about the desired result? What kind of output do you want in the footnote? Do you want the entries from footnotes to appear in the bibliography at the end? In a separate bibliography? Not at all? Do you want to differentiate the different source types with the cite command you use to cite them (that's how I read the question at the moment) or would it make more sense to differentiate them based on entry data or some other ad-hoc classification in the preamble? Is it possible that the same source would be cited with both styles?

Comment: Moewe, thanks for your interest. The ultimate goal of doing the work through biblatex is to be able to use the op. cit., and ibidem automatically in the footnotes, since in the books of this collection the sources are many, really many to try to keep track of the op. cit., and ibidem manually.

In the author/year style, is not placed op. cit. or ibidem.

The final list only contains the references

Comment: I leave in this link I leave a sample

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7h7yf4n8rscdv3u/Screenshot_20230513_100818.png?dl=1

Comment: Please don't link to off-site samples. Instead include them directly in your question. It would still help if you could edit your question to describe your goal more clearly. (Comments are usually meant to be temporary and it can be hard to find the exact specifications if they are split over several comments.)